# Google apps script function runs fine 90% of the time but occasionally throws an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a function to import the content of a ".CSV" file into Google Sheet, and it does work fine 90% of the time. Here is the code I am using:

```js
function listCsvFiles() {
  var files  = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  var fileList = [];
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    var fName = file.getName();
    fileList.push(" \\n" + fName);
    
    
  }
  return fileList;

}

function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the data file in your Google Drive,\\n"
                                  +"for example:\\n"
                                  + listCsvFiles(), Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  
  var searchTerm = "title = '"+fileName+"'";

 
 
  
   
  // searching for  the file
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchTerm);
  var csvFile = "";
   
  // Looping through the results
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    // assuming the first is the one we want
    if (file.getName() == fileName) {
      // get file as a string
      csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      break;
    }
  }
  // parseCsv  returns a [][] array writable to a sheet
 
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // dropping the data to a sheet
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); 
}
```

However, after multiple successful executions, randomly will throw the following error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

[Here you can see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqbd0.png)

[The line in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0mJc.png)

I can't explain to myself why it works OK most of the time, but then throws an error.
Please bear in mind the above code is bonded to a spreadsheet. Closing the spreadsheet and then opening it again is the remedy for now, but trying to figure out why it happens in the first place. Any suggestions are welcome and please do not judge me too hard as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to catch the error like:

```
if(csvData != null){
   sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}else{
   Logger.log(csvData);
}
```

After the error occurs, you can check the log and check the file that was causing the problem.

For me it looks like you trying to use a csvFile which was not found a or something else is going wrong in this line: `csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();`

Comment: Adding here that logging `csvData` when you know it is in the else condition is kind of useless. You already know that it will cater the else condition if it is null, so you'll be just logging `null` always. Instead, print the input which is `filename` and `csvFile` to further confirm if the filename is really valid (present in the drive) or not. Then OP should be able to proceed from there to debug the issue.